# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Quiero borrar un usuario de un treeview con este código:

```
def borrar_producto(self):
    self.mensaje['text'] = ''
    try:
        self.formulario.item(self.formulario.selection())['text'][1]
    except IndexError as Error:
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Seleccione un empleado'
        return
    self.wish_delete()`
```

Sin embargo, me da este error:

> self.formulario.item(self.formulario.selection())['text'][1]
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te dice el error es que **el objeto que obtienes como resultado de la llamada a `self.formulario.item(self.formulario.selection())['text']` no es un objeto que se pueda tratar como un contenedor** (algo que contiene otros objetos o una lista como lo estás tratando tú al hacer `[1]`).

En realidad obtienes **un int** (por ello lo de TypeError: 'int') al cual no le puedes preguntar por ningún otro objeto que pueda contener, **no es un contenedor**.