# buenas no encuentro el error en las opciones 3 y 4 del menu

Tags: python-3.8

La traza de error es:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/MI/Desktop/final algoritmos/FinalDiciembre@2020.py", line 77, in <module>
    ElDiego.menu()
  File "c:/Users/MI/Desktop/final algoritmos/FinalDiciembre@2020.py", line 67, in menu
    ElDiego.selectionSort(ElDiego.herencia)
  File "c:/Users/MI/Desktop/final algoritmos/FinalDiciembre@2020.py", line 33, in selectionSort
    min_index = i[2]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

El código es:

```
# Python 3.8
# VSCode

class ElDiego():

    herencia = [["Blindado", 500000], ["Ferrari", 155000000]]
    ElDiez = [["Napoli", "Champions League", 3], ["Napoli", "Libertadores", 3], ["Barcelona", "Intercontinental", 5],["Boca Juniors", "Liga Local", 1]]
    ListaFinal = []

    def AgregarTrofeo():
        eD = []
        for x in range(3):
            if x == 0:
                eD.append(input("Ingresa el nombre del equipo equipo: "))
            elif x == 1:
                eD.append(input("Ingrese el trofeo que gano: "))
            elif x == 2:
                eD.append(int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de veces que lo gano: ")))
        ElDiego.ElDiez.append(eD)

    def agregarHerencia():
        hr = []
        for q in range(2):
            if q == 0:
                hr.append(input("ingrese el objeto: "))
            elif q == 1:
                hr.append(int(input("ingrese el valor del objeto: ")))
        ElDiego.herencia.append(hr)

    def selectionSort(L):
        for i in range(len(L)-1):
            min_index = i[2]
            for j in range(i+1, len(L)-1):
                if L[j[2]] < L[min_index]:
                    min_index = j
            L[i], L[min_index] = L[min_index], L[i]

    def insertionSort(L):
        for i in range(1, len(L)):
            key = L[i]
            j = i-1
            while j[2] >= 0 and key[2] < L[j[2]]:
                L[j+1] = L[j]
                j -= 1
            L[j+1] = key

    def menu():
        print('---------------MENU----------------')
        print('-      1)Agregar herencia         -')
        print('-      2)Agregar un trofeo        -')
        print('- 3)Mostrar herencia por valor    -')
        print('- 4)Mostrar trofeos por cantidad  -')
        print('-            5)Salir              -')
        print('-----------------------------------')

        op = input("Ingrese una opcion: ")
        if op == '1':
            ElDiego.agregarHerencia()
            print(ElDiego.herencia)
            ElDiego.menu()
        elif op == '2':
            ElDiego.AgregarTrofeo()
            print(ElDiego.ElDiez)
            ElDiego.menu()
        elif op == '3':
            ElDiego.selectionSort(ElDiego.herencia)
            ElDiego.menu()
        elif op == '4':
            ElDiego.insertionSort(ElDiego.ElDiez)
            ElDiego.menu()
        elif op == '5':
            exit()
        else:
            print("Elija una opcion valida!")
            ElDiego.menu()
ElDiego.menu()
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/302965/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 0):

pude arreglar uno de los metodos:

```
def insertionSort(L):
    for i in range(1, len(L)):
        key = L[i]
        key2 = L[i][2]
        j = i-1
        while j >= 0 and key2 > L[j][2]:
            L[j+1] = L[j]
            j -= 1
        L[j+1] = key
    print(L)
```